# using sed or similar to modify lines in a file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a huge file composed of the following:

```
this is text

1234.1234567

this is another text

1234.1234567
```

and so on

I would like to transfer it to:

```
this is text:1234.1234567

this is another text:1234.1234567
```

is this possible using sed? or any other similar command?

Thanks

Comment: You want to join lines using a `:` as separator?

Comment: @janos pretty much yes. but so that each line will contain the text and the number beneath it separated by a :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to join lines using `:` as separator, you could use `paste`:

```
paste -d : - - < file.txt
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -v sep=: '{ if (NR % 2 == 0) { print prev sep $0 } else prev = $0 }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have lines containing just alphabets and other containing floating point numbers, you can do the following:

```
awk '/[a-zA-Z]+/ {printf "%s:", $0}
     /[0-9.]+/ {print $0}' data
```

`data` is the filename.  You can redirect the output to another file.